# how to design a reactive visualization graph for a time series using shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I want to design a reactive interaction graph for a time series for shiny.

It is used for when I have a time series. I change the first point of the time series.

Then I can get the reactive graph changed for the point changed.

I have trouble for how to assign the value input into the function. Specifically, for the

yinput<-sensi(num). I want to the input be some number range from 0.1 to 0.9.but my sensitive's

function only allow to enter one input.

Is there any idea for that?

Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)

sensi<-function(input)
{
  
y<-c(input,5,12,21,30,50,90,100)

return(y)

}


Date = c("2020/07/16","2020/07/23","2020/07/30","2020/08/06","2020/08/13","2020/08/20","2020/08/27","2020/09/13")


num<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)
yinput<-sensi(num)
df <- data.frame(yinput, Date = as.Date(Date))



ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=h4("plot1", align="center")),
  sidebarPanel( 
    sliderInput("num", "Number:",min = 0, max = 0.9,value=0.5)),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot2")))

server <- function(input,output){
  
  dat <- reactive({
    test <- df[df$num %in% seq(from=min(input$num),to=max(input$num),by=1),]
    print(test)
    test
  })
  
  output$plot2<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(df) + aes(Date, y) + geom_line()})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a random number as the input to `sensi()`? That would be `sensi(input = .1 + .8 * runif(1))`

Comment: Try to include _as little code as necessary_ in your question.

Comment: I am trying to let user type the input 。sensi（input） a is the input sidebar which show at the left side of the dashboard

Comment: I think you might need to revise some of your basic Shiny knowledge. Have you seen RStudio's introduction to Shiny course? I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's a very basic example

You should be doing your 'thinking' inside your 'server' function.

Hopefully this example will show you how reactive inputs and outputs relate to each other, and you can extend it to your plot.

```r
require(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("num", "Number:", min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = 0.5),
  textOutput("number_display")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$number_display <- 
    renderText({
      as.character(input$num)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Where I've said `as.character(input$num)`, you'll want to do something with num to make your plot.